# How to get Text of selected menu item in asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net

I have Menu bind with xml file. Now i am trying to get text of selected item with the help of which i can filter my database and display contents from database to the body of my.aspx page

Comment: can you give some more details and code so we can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: i am sorry i am unable to show code because there is no code actually.

Comment: i am sorry i have no codes in .cs file actually. But i can Explain the whole thing. 
I have masterpage.master with a menu (menuitem1,menuitem2) and a Lable1. Now what i Actually want is: if I click or Select the Menuitem, the Lable1.Text Should be changed to the selected-menu-item-text . 
This Much
ThankYOu For Help

Answer (score 0):

this is only the code behind after clicking on menu. it's work on mine

```
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 protected void MenuName_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem selectedItem = MenuName.SelectedItem;
    Label1.Text = MenuName.SelectedItem.Text ;
}
```